# Add captions to looped slider plugin?

Tags: jquery, slider, captions

I am implementing the looped slider plugin (see: http://nathansearles.com/loopedslider/example-4.html) on a website, and need to add captions to the images (that just appear as text beneath their corresponding images).

Could anyone point me in a direction of where I could start? There is already so much jquery going on in this plugin...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [example-3](http://nathansearles.com/loopedslider/example-3.html), you can see the author added text below the image using a paragraph inside the list item, like this:

```
<ul class="slides">
 <li><img src="image-01.jpg" width="500" height="375" alt="First Image" />
  <p>Add a caption here</p>
 </li>
 <li><img src="image-02.jpg" width="500" height="375" alt="Second Image" /></li>
 <li><img src="image-03.jpg" width="500" height="375" alt="Third Image" /></li>
 <li><img src="image-04.jpg" width="500" height="375" alt="Fourth Image" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're a whiz! I couldn't see the demo-proper - but that's what I was looking for. Thank you again, young Fudgey!